# Is this a morphism of sheaves?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Consider the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, equipped with the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of holomorphic functions  $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. I'm looking at the following map of sheaves

$$ \varphi: \mathcal{F} \to  \mathcal{F}, \, \, \, f \mapsto f^2 + 1.$$

I am trying to figure out if this actually *is* a map of sheaves. (That is, whether the map $\varphi$ commutes with the various restriction maps on $\mathbb{C}$.) My gut tells me that $\varphi$ should be a map of sheaves; I mean, $\varphi$ is a polynomial in it's input! But when I go to check that $\varphi$ commutes with the restriction maps, it seems impossibly complicated. It would involve knowing exactly how $\varphi$ acts every open set of the complex plane. So far, I've tried showing that $\varphi$ commutes with the restriction map from $\mathbb{C}$ to the open unit disk. This already is quite complicated, since it involves figuring out how $\varphi$ acts on $D$, which isn't obvious at first sight. I have two questions here:

1. Is there an easy way to check that this map commutes with the restriction maps? I'm looking for something along the lines of: "if $\varphi$ is a polynomial in its input, then it commutes with restriction maps." Or is there no general rule like this, in which case we have to check each example by hand?
2. More generally, is there an easy test (like the one I mentioned above) that we can use to generate many examples of maps of sheaves? This could be a test that applies for this particular example of a sheaf, or other sheaves as well (e.g: continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, smooth functions on a manifold, etc.)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U \subseteq V$ be open subsets of the complex plane, so that we have a restriction mapping $f \mapsto f|_{U} : \mathcal F(V) \to \mathcal F(U)$. Note that the definition of $f|_U$ is given by $f|_U(z) = f(z)$. Now let $f \in \mathcal F(V)$ be arbitrary. We have to check that $(f|_{U})^2 + 1 = (f^2 + 1)|_{U}$. To see that two functions on $U$ agree, let us take $z \in U$ arbitrary. We then have
$$
((f|_U)^2 + 1)(z) = (f|_U)^2(z) + 1 = (f|_U(z))^2 + 1 = f(z)^2 + 1 = (f^2 + 1)(z) = (f^2 + 1)|_U(z).
$$
It is worth emphasizing that essentially no mathematics happens in this sequence of equations: it is just seeing through all the notation.

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking this. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

The direct method is actually quite simple – you may be lost in the formalism though.

I’m of course assuming that you’re assuming that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is, for each open subset $U$, the space of holomorphic functions $U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and that the restriction of $\mathcal{F}$ is the usual notion of restriction for a function. (You didn’t specify otherwise, even though it is important.)

If $U \subset V \subset \mathbb{C}$ are nonempty open subsets, and if $f \in \mathcal{F}(V)$, then $\varphi(V)(f)=f^2+1$, so that its restriction to $U$ is $h:z \in U \longmapsto f(z)^2+1$. On the other hand, the restriction $g$ of $f$ to $U$ is $z \in U \longmapsto g(z)=f(z)$. Now $\varphi(U)(g)$ is $z \longmapsto (g^2+1)(z)=g(z)^2+1$, so that $\varphi(U)(g)=h$, QED.